# Git Branching trouble query with terminal

Tags: git, branch

I know these questions are simple but I'm having problems with branching:

When I make a new branch, am I supposed to download separate files or use that same folder to make changes? If so how do I? Just a git clone?

How do I push commits to another branch?

Would it be just git commit blah blah?
Git push origin branch name?

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking. Does this help? [https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1) When I make a new branch, am I supposed to download separate files or use that same folder to make changes?

Let's say you are on origBranch (you can check with git branch) and you want to create newBranch

```
    git checkout -b newBranch
```

Now you are on newBranch which is the same as origBranch. Any changes committed will now be in only newBranch.

Q2) How do I push commits to another branch? Would it be just git commit blah blah Git push origin branch name.

If you would like to push just the newBranch, it's

```
    git push -u origin newBranch
```

If you would like to add commits from newBranch in to origBranch, there are several approaches.

**Merge approach:**

```
    git checkout origBranch
    git merge newBranch
    git push
```

**Rebase Approach:**

```
    git checkout newBranch
    git rebase origBranch
```

**Cherry pick approach:**

```
    git checkout origBranch
    git cherry-pick <commit_id from newBranch>
    git push
```

**Pull request approach:**

1. Go to repro on git hub
2. Select new pull request
3. From the base drop down, select origBranch
4. From the compare drop down, select newBranch
5. Add in notes or assignees to review
6. Select Create Pull Request